# MVC 3 - Getting on server side the value from a dropdown changed on javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a javascript that change the value from my dropdown, and when I save the form, the value can't be captured on server side.

Follow bellow some of the code:

```
  <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
        Model.Categorias
            .Where(c => c.Id != Model.ContentId)
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem {
                Selected = c.Id == Model.CategoriaId,
                Text = c.Type + " - " +c.Name,
                Value = c.Id.ToString()
            } ),
            "Selecione uma Categoria")

         @Html.Hidden("hdnValue", Model.hndCategoriaId) // my hidden value
  </div>
```

Javascript that change the dropdown and the hidden value

```
function change(item) {

var valueArtigo;
var ddl = document.getElementById('Categoria_CategoriaId');         
for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
   if (ddl.options[i].text.toUpperCase().indexOf("ARTIGOS") != -1)
   valueArtigo = ddl.options[i].value;
}
document.getElementById("Categoria_CategoriaId").value = valueArtigo;
document.getElementById("Categoria_hdnValue").value = valueArtigo;
}
```

Getting back on server side, I am trying to save the value on database.

```
public void UpdateCategoriaForContentItem(ContentItem item, EditCategoriaViewModel model)
{
    if ((model.CategoriaId != null)||(model.hndCategoriaId != null)) // both are null
    {...}
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You need to bind the hidden value to the model

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.hdnCategoriaId)
or
@Html.Hidden("hdnCategoriaId",Model.hdnCategoriaId,Model)
```

To set the value of the hidden field on dropdown change event you can simply do

```
$('#hdnCategoriaId').val(valueArtigo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likly, your problem isn't in javascript but in binding. Try select and submit without javascript to test purposes and look what will be posted in request to server and how will it be mapped on action parameters.